# error sending client object to server

Tags: java, object, client, send

I cannot send an object by client to server because when i run client the server program crash getting me "Connection reset" error

This is the client:

```
    public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 4444);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        Group g = new Group("EXAMPLE");
        String command = "ADD_GROUP";
        System.out.println("Sending: " + command);
        oos.writeUTF(command);
        oos.flush();
        oos.writeObject(g);
        oos.flush();
        s.close();
     }

}
```

This is the server:

```
    public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException
    {

       ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);

       System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

       SimpleDataSource.init("database.properties");
       Network net = new Network();

       while (true)
       {
          Socket s = server.accept();
          InetAddress clientAddress = s.getInetAddress();
          System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + clientAddress.getHostName() + "[" + clientAddress.getHostAddress() + "]");

          ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass(s,net);
          service.doService();

       }
    }
}
```

And this is ServiceClass class:

```
    public class ServiceClass{

    private Socket s;
    private Network net;

    public ServiceClass(Socket s, Network net){
        this.s = s;
        this.net = net;
    }

    public void doService() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException
    {
       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

       while(true){

            String line = (String) ois.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Received: " + line);

            if(line.equals("ADD_GROUP")){
                Group group = (Group) ois.readObject();
                net.addGroup(group);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i run server it wait for client to connect and when i run my client program server crash getting me this error:

```
    Waiting for clients to connect...
Incoming connection from: UNKNOWN_DEVICE[192.168.1.3]
Received: ADD_GROUP
Error: Group already exists
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
    at social_network.ServiceClass.doService(ServiceClass.java:35)
    at social_network.Server.main(Server.java:39)
Java Result: 1
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Try it again after removing `s.close();` from server class that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Braj No, it is not causing the error. The server is getting a 'connection reset' exception when reading. It never gets to the a.close() line.

Comment: i've made it and i've edited my code with new error log

Comment: @Braj It has already been found. The code is complete enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client isn't closing the socket, so the server can get a connection reset instead of an EOFException when it tries to read the non-existent second string.

When  you fix that, EOFException means there is nothing left to read. It isn't a problem. You just catch it, and break.